# How was plate armour attached and secured?

Tags: middle-ages, armour

I can see from this [quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-medieval-plate-armor-use-unarmored-leather-straps-to-hold-it-together-Wouldnt-these-get-cut-in-battle-rendering-the-armor-useless) leather straps were used throughout history, but was that all that was used, and where *typically* (if there's well defined types of attachment) did various parts attach to and from?

All I could find was a [list of armour components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_medieval_armour_components), but that page explicitly does not

> identify fastening components or various appendages [...] or clothing

So I'm left wondering what was used and how, to attach and secure armour?

Comment: I've found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-knIUGLVms) from university of Southampton on how to dress a plate armour, it shows quite well all the pieces and how they were attached

Comment: @DanM, I can't access youtube at the moment, but if you were able to transcribe the most salient points it would *definitely* make *at least* the start of a good answer.

Comment: Do we assume that there was one standard method?  Or would the method have varied by manufacturer?

Comment: @MCW I'd assume if one or more methods worked really well, then all the armourers/fitters would either share that knowledge or stumble upon it independantly?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have a look at how individual pieces of armour can be attached, you could take a look at the online shops which target medieval enthusiasts and re-enactors.

Visit the site below, and look for individual pieces.

While, this is strictly speaking not totally, historically accurate, it should give you a good guideline of how it can work.

[Plate armour section from a German shop](https://vehi-mercatus.de/Plattenruestung), which shows some of the individual pieces in the context of the wearer. There are plenty of other online shops, which offer different pieces and styles of armour.

---

Here's a loose list of informative YouTube Channels, feel free to expand the list.

- **Knyght Errant**: [The website](https://knyghterrant.com), and [the YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/KnyghtErrant/videos)

This channel is thematically dead-on if you look for information regarding plate armour and everything that goes with it, i.e., the soft kit underneath, maintenance, etc.

Comment: It might be worth also pointing out videos by Toby Capwell, as {here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvNhje84Iwg). He is not only a historian but also a re-enactor for more than two decades. He notes that while there are have been some useful modern innovations in armour, for the most part re-enactors have, over the past 40 years, *rediscovered* authentic Medieval techniques and design decisions as they have perfected their craft.

Comment: Yes, and many more. I intentionally did not list YouTube channels, of which several spring to mind, since the OP mentioned in a comment that he/she hasn't access to YouTube. I will add a list of informative channels to my answer nevertheless.

Comment: If you have access to a university library I am sure Capwell has published papers as well. He is an active historian and Medieval European armour is his specialty

Answer (score -3):

If you play the video game Batman: Arkham Knight, it actually borrows the same concept: The suit is armor worn underneath a [image: image of a video game character wearing modern armor] to hold the armor plates.

Real knights used similar systems, knights wore a long tunic shirt called a aketon or gambeson which had attachment points to tie one's armor on.

[image: historically accurate gambeson]

<sub>[Men's gambeson, c. 1660–1670. Collection Centraal Museum, Utrecht.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambeson#/media/File:Kolder,_ca._1660-1670.jpg)</sub>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8-eeJUcO5M

Comment: I'm not confident the analogy with that video game is either a) an accurate representation or b) relevant?